# Understanding React css hierarchy

Tags: css, angular, reactjs, sass

I come form an Angular background. In Angular, you have a global styles. When you overwrite the same classes in your component's styles, then it gets overwritten just fine.

In React, I have created my own global styles and imported it at the top of my `index.js` using `import './global-styles.scss';`. This makes the global styles reach all components just fine. My problem is I can't overwrite the global styles in my local "component" styles. I know I can use "hacks" like `!important` but that is not the type of solution I am looking for.

**How can I change things to have my local "component" styles overwrite my "global" styles?**

*If you come form an Angular background then you will understand exactly what I mean, for React people, I hope my question makes sense :)*

Comment: Hmm, can you check the specificity of the both the css elements?

Comment: Since you are loading the global css in the top level component, so it must overwrite your component styles. Only reason that I see is the specificity.